# Why map frame is not continuous?

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [rep-0105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html),it says "The map frame is not continuous, meaning the pose of a mobile platform in the map frame can change in discrete jumps at any time."

In my opinion, the map frame (on navigation application) is a global coordinate,its three axis is continuous, and the robot pose on that coordinate can be change over time.

Is that right?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12861/why-map-frame-is-not-continuous?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map frame is the result of a localization node. Typical global localization algorithms such as SLAM for instance are absolute but movements in the map frame is not continuous due to sensor noise for instance.

Therefore, it is better not to inject them directly into the robot command. On the opposite,
the odometry provided by the PR2 wheel encoders for instance are continuous but is less and less precise over time. See robot_pose_ekf for instance as a way to merge both strategies.

So yes you are right, the map frame provide a global position of the robot base link. However, depending on your localization algorithm this position may "jump".

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-02-02**:
map  is a frame which does not move. The transformation linking map to base_link changes over time and is updated by a localization node.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-02**:
It would be better to word it as "Movement in the map frame is not continuous."

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-02**:
So map frame(a coordinate) is fixed not move or change by SLAM or localization node, and the only moved thing is the robot pose,right?